# How could I display a JDialog with item names that are below a specific quantity from a database?

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, netbeans, orm

How could I display a JDialog with item names that are below a specific quantity? I would need this in a Java database application developed with Hibernate 5.4 and Apache Derby in the NetBeans IDE. I am quite a newbie and would appreciate every help!

Below you can see the entity-relationship diagram of the database's tables:

[Click link to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zpni.png)

Here is the JDialog where the items below a specific limit would be displayed:

[Clink link to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amElv.jpg)

Here is the window where the user enters the quantity limit:

[Clink link to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8qBG.jpg)

Code segment for entering limit:

```
public class SetQuantityLimit extends javax.swing.JFrame{
public static int limit
...
private void enterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
limit = Integer.paerseInt(this.JTextField.getText());
```

As a static variable *limit* should outlive this method and class, shouldn't it? Thus when I call this variable in the other class that should display the message when the stock window is opened in the application...

```
public class LimitMessage extends javax.swing.JDialog
```

...it should have its value, am I right? So this is what I have:

```
private void FillData()
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
dtm.addColumn("Name")
List<Items> result = null;
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = null;
Transaction tx = null;
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery("...");
result = query.list();
tx.commit();
session.close();

//itemModel is an instance of ItemModel() DAO class with methods such as create, update, delete etc., see picture below
for (Items item : this.itemModel.findAll()){
dtm.addRow(new Object[]{...});
this.JTable.setModel(dtm);}
...
```

This method should display the name of the items below the item limit in the JTable. The problem is that the quantity of items is calculated with the TRANSACTIONS.Flow and ADVICENOTE.In_Or_Out columns and table associations, and not stored in the database, which could be problematic. I am quite lost, I am not sure whether I should calculate here the quantity again or can I use the calculations from stock view where the quantities are calculated anyway. Maybe I should revamp the whole database structure to make it more reasonable...Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated!

**Items.java**

```
package classes;

public class Items  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int itemId;
     private String name;
     private Integer netPrice;
     private Integer vatRate;
     private Categories category;

    public Items() {
    }

    public Items(int itemId, String name, Integer netPrice, Integer vatRate, Categories category) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.name = name;
        this.netPrice = netPrice;
        this.vatRate = vatRate;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return this.itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getNetPrice() {
        return this.netPrice;
    }

    public void setNetPrice(Integer netPrice) {
        this.netPrice = netPrice;
    }
    public Integer getVatRate() {
        return this.vatRate;
    }

    public void setVatRate(Integer vatRate) {
        this.vatRate = vatRate;
    }

    public Categories getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Categories category) {
        this.category = category;
    }


}
```

**Items.hbm.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Items" table="ITEMS" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="itemId" type="int" column="ITEM_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME" length="100"/>
        <property name="netPrice" type="java.lang.Integer" column="NET_PRICE"/>
        <property name="vatRate" type="java.lang.Integer" column="VAT_RATE"/>
        <many-to-one name="category" class="classes.Categories" fetch="select" column="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" lazy="false"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: After getting all items using `itemModel.findAll()`, you are not filtering items by `limit`. So, I guess all the items appear in the dialog. Isn't it?

Comment: That's correct! So what would be the best way to filter it?

Comment: Please add the code of `Items` class to the question.

Comment: sorry for the delay I have updated my question with Items class and its mapping